# Configure ListenOptions.UseHttps with .pem file rather than .pfx in ASP.NET 6.0 app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate, kestrel

I have an ASP.NET web app on ubuntu 20.04, and I am using SSL certificate in `.pfx` format, which works fine. However, I want to learn how to do the same with the `.pem` file.

I know it can be done in `appsettings.json` like this and through the `HttpsFromPem` key:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "HttpsInlineCertAndKeyFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "<path to .pem/.crt file>",
          "KeyPath": "<path to .key file>",
          "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I know how to use the `.pfx` format like so:

```
var httpsCert = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_CERT");
var httpsCertKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_CERT_KEY");

if (httpsCert != null && httpsCertKey != null)
{
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001,
               listenOptions => listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsCert, httpsCertKey));
}
```

Source - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0

My question is: how to configure Kestrel to read cert from the `.pem` file in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just load it in using

```
var pemPath = //read in from configuration
var privateKeyPath = //read in from configuration
var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(pemPath, privateKeyPath);
```

Then you can configure Kestrel with something like this when you're configuring Kestrel.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(adapterOptions =>
            {
                adapterOptions.ServerCertificate = certificate
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**.NET 7**

[`X509Certificate2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-7.0) has a method [`CreateFromPemFile(certPemFilePath, keyPemFilePath)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.createfrompemfile?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2-createfrompemfile(system-string-system-string)):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var pemFile = "cert.pem";
var keyFile = "cert.key";
var port = 5001;  // builder.Configuration.GetSection("https_port").Get<int>();

builder.WebHost
    .ConfigureKestrel(options => {

        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port, listenOptions => {

            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;

            var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(pemFile, keyFile);
            listenOptions.UseHttps(cert);
        });

    });
```